# How to differentiate TemplateBindings when they have the same name

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have toggle buttons and would like to create a style tree for them. The goal is to have a main style and control template (with TemplateBinding's) - then each different looking button will have it's own style and I can simply change some Setter Properties to adjust whatever I need. This saves me having to make a possibly massive control template for each button. This also saves time when I want to change the way they all look. With the toggle button, I would like to have two paths inside it, and a trigger for IsChecked to change the opacity (Path1 will be default, Path2 will be the visible one when checked). However I cannot differentiate between the two Path.Data's since the mini-style won't accept TargetName, and Triggers don't accept TemplateBindings.

Example:

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,1,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Border.Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="{DynamicResource FillBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Path.StrokeThickness" Value="0"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Viewbox 
                    x:Name="viewbox" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Width="Auto" 
                    Height="Auto">
                    <Border 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                        Width="16" 
                        Height="16" 
                        BorderThickness="0" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        x:Name="border" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Border.Padding}">
                        <Grid 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                            Width="Auto" 
                            Height="Auto">
                            <Path 
                                Opacity="1"
                                Margin="2" 
                                Name="ButtonPath1" 
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Path.Fill}" 
                                Stretch="Fill" 
                                StrokeEndLineCap="Round" 
                                StrokeStartLineCap="Round" 
                                StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding Path.StrokeThickness}" 
                                Data="{TemplateBinding Path.Data}"   <!-- This one -->
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                           <Path 
                                Opacity="0"
                                Margin="2" 
                                Name="ButtonPath2" 
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Path.Fill}" 
                                Stretch="Fill" 
                                StrokeEndLineCap="Round" 
                                StrokeStartLineCap="Round" 
                                StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding Path.StrokeThickness}" 
                                Data="{TemplateBinding Path.Data}"   <!-- And this one -->
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Viewbox>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonPath1" Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonPath2" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonPath1" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonPath2" Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style 
    x:Key="ActualButton" 
    TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultToggleButton}">

<!-- How can I point the properties below to the correct Path.Data? 
     Setting TargetName did not work since it is in a different Style. -->

    <Setter Property="Path.Data" Value="M 0 0 L 6 0 L 3 6 Z"/>     <!-- ButtonPath -->
    <Setter Property="Path.Data" Value="M 0 6 L 3 0 L 6 6 Z"/>     <!-- ButtonPath2 -->
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not be a good idea, but I managed to make this work by moving the "IsChecked" trigger into the ActualButton (instead of the Default) style, under Style.Triggers.

Example:

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,1,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Border.Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="{DynamicResource FillBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Path.StrokeThickness" Value="0"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Viewbox 
                    x:Name="viewbox" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Width="Auto" 
                    Height="Auto">
                    <Border 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                        Width="16" 
                        Height="16" 
                        BorderThickness="0" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        x:Name="border" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Border.Padding}">
                        <Grid 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                            Width="Auto" 
                            Height="Auto">
                            <Path 
                                Opacity="1"
                                Margin="2" 
                                Name="ButtonPath1" 
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Path.Fill}" 
                                Stretch="Fill" 
                                StrokeEndLineCap="Round" 
                                StrokeStartLineCap="Round" 
                                StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding Path.StrokeThickness}" 
                                Data="{TemplateBinding Path.Data}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style 
    x:Key="ActualButton" 
    TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Path.Data" Value="M 0 0 L 6 0 L 3 6 Z"/> 
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Path.Data" Value="M 0 6 L 3 0 L 6 6 Z"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>       
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `TemplateBinding` takes the value from the actual control to which you applied the template, so it can provide you a single value not different value for different controls. As you are using `Path.Data` at two different places with `TemplateBinding`, it will give you the same value at both places. If you want different value then bind it with two different properties.

I think you can do this by creating a custom `DependencyProperty` of type Path for you `ToggleButton`. One for unchecked and other for checked.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about this suggestion for a while but ended up figuring out another way.